# .net core reference conflict with phantom assembly version

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

When I build my asp.net core 2.2 app, I get a warning saying

```
 There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
 References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [/Users/yurypastushenko/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.abstractions/2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll].
     /Users/yurypastushenko/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.abstractions/2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll
       Project file item includes which caused reference "/Users/yurypastushenko/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.abstractions/2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll".
         /Users/yurypastushenko/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.abstractions/2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll
 References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
     /Users/yurypastushenko/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions/2.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
       Project file item includes which caused reference "/Users/yurypastushenko/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions/2.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll".
         Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
```

Notice the empty list [] after `References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"`.

Does this mean that I have no references to version 2.0.3? Then why is this reference conflict happens?

Did anyone meet a similar problem?

Comment: Which `nuget` packages do you in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavel, thank you for your comment. While trying to answer, I came across the two references in .csproj files:

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
```

I have no idea how did they get there, but obviously they are the reason of the conflicts. After deleting them everything compiles without warnings.